# Fixing Broken Package Installation--Install Stalling other installations

Tags: package-management, java

Awhile back I was trying to install a particular level of java to make an application run.  Given that the support was no longer available, this is no longer viable.  I have removed all of the repositories that were causing errors.

However, now when just trying to do something simple like installing wine I am getting the following error:

Unable to remove Wine : 
Error while installing package:installed oracle-java-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried one last thing and it appears to have worked.  I went in and tracked down the actual package and just nixed it.  Not sure why that worked this time and it wasn't removed when I removed everything else.